# unmet dependencies while trying to install phpmyadmin on LAMP stack

Tags: apt, apache2, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpmyadmin along with LAMP stack but when I write to the terminal `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` I get this errors :

```
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                   php5-mysqli but it is not installable or
                   php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install php5-gd and I got this error :

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-gd : Depends: php5-common (= 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3) but 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have `php5-common` already install I tried to install `5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1` but I get the there package is not found .

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix the `broken packages` then try again.

Comment: Already tried it